# Magento 2 : Change image sizes in fotorama

Tags: magento2, image, fotorama, image-resizing

How do I change the images sizes of the fotorama gallery ?

From what I understand I need to edit my view.xml

But what Image Id's do I need to change please.

Also do I need to run some mage command after to see the changes ?

Thanks.

Comment: on which version you are ?

Comment: are you using luma theme ?

Comment: Nope its a custom theme I have noticed that changing the XML changes the size of the fotorama frame but the images are not resized.

Comment: which id you are editing ? `product_page_image_small` is the is for gallery image